# Does Laravel need cleanup before production?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6.2

When I did `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel nameofdirectory` I saw that Laravel 6.2 is 143MB to start with! I was wondering if having all those plugins extends the attack surface of Laravel applications. Someone mentioned that may be just the development environment, and I know there are things like outputting errors to the browser that should be turned off before production. I wonder if there are other ways to minimize the size and number of libraries running with it?

From what I can see, production deployment of something you've been working on would include
setting up a new database, then

1. Copying all the files over,
2. changing .env in production to `APP_DEBUG=false`, `APP_ENV=production` and maybe some other values including db user you set up.
3. Some clean up of libraries you aren't using??
4. Optionally using some sorts of [cache server side](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/integrate-laravel-cache/)?

perhaps I'm missing a step or two..?

I'm wondering if the presence of all the different libraries in /vendor could be a security risk though - assuming the same code quality I might expect twice as many vulnerabilities as Wordpress which has about half as much code.? but as I understand it /public is the only publically accessible region and unlike Wordpress you can't directly go to wp-content/plugins/blah.php.

What is the best way to clean up unnecessary libraries, if needed, on production?

Comment: I do `composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev` as suggested by laravel's official documentation. I don't know if it really works though. [link](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/deployment)